# Django models : Inverted index on timestamp with query for 'n' latest rows

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have the datetime filled with auto_now=True
Database is mysql.
Range queries won't work for me directly.
Is there any one liner for this?

**For simplicity, how can I get 10 rows with highest values for a field(let it be Integerfield) ?**

Comment: For simplicity, how can I get 10 rows with highest values for a field(let it be Integerfield) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For model `Model` with integer field `field`, this should work:

```
top10 = Model.objects.order_by('-field')[:10]
```

If you want django to have an index on the field, you need to define it in the model with [db_index](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#db-index) option:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    field = IntegerField(db_index=True)
```

Regular database index should work even if your asking for the highest values.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of doing this since this will sort the whole table first which is expensive for a large table?

Comment: You just need to add index to the table, MySQL will use it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

order by the field in descending order and limit to 10?

```
ORDER BY fieldname DESC LIMIT 10
```